# bash invalid delimiter in cut command

Tags: bash, cut

```
tab="`\echo '\t'`"

grep "^.*${tab}.*${tab}.*${tab}.*${tab}.*${tab}" $file | 
  grep -vi ssm_id |
    cut -f 1,5,6 -d "${tab}" > $rmloadfile
```

I am getting error as

```
-cut: invalid delimiter
```

the above code is part of my bash script.

Comment: You can use ANSI C strings -- `tab=$'\t'`

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/35369/how-to-cut-by-tab-character

Comment: Note that `cut` uses tabs as the delimiter by default, so there's no need to specify *anything* here.

Answer (score 3):

Ignoring the actual problem, you really want to use `awk` here instead of this combination of `grep` and `cut`:

```
awk 'NF>=6 && tolower($0) !~ ssm_id { print $1, $5, $6 }' $file > $rmloadfile
```

Comment: +1 for GNU `awk` one can use `IGNORECASE` for case insensitive match.

Answer (score 2):

The `echo` command doesn't interpret backslash escaped characters by default. It has to be enabled using the `-e` switch.

If you use:

```
tab="$(echo -e '\t')"
```

it works.

But I'd rather recommend using the approach proposed by @devnull in the comments, or refer to the linked question.